# Deploying reports ssrs 2012 wont update linked reports

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, deployment, report

I have ssrs 2012 installed and sometimes when I deploy the reports via VS, certain linked reports won't update. The only solution I've found is to remove the linked reports and create a new linked report.

Anyone had this situation before and any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: do you make changes in both main report and linked report and deploy only the main report? if so, please deploy both. ReportServer will consider only those which are already deployed.

Comment: I only make changes in the main report. This is the one I deployed. The linked report stays intact.

Comment: so what does it mean when you say `certain linked reports won't update.`

Comment: It means that sometimes the "linked reports" does update. Sometimes they don't. I'm not sure if its a permission issue. What do you think?

Comment: why would a "linked report" need to update if you did not make changes to it? Please explain what are you trying to do, what is happening and what is expected?